# Fixed Header Under Navbar Menu

Tags: semantic-ui

How to create a header menu under navbar menu which is fixed, like VTiger Dashboard :

Here is mine :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
});
```

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

body{
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.ui.grid.main{
 margin-top: 70px;
}

.padding-reset{
 padding: 0px !important;
}

.ui.message{
 padding: 40px !important;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
   .ui.grid.main{
    margin-top: 70px;
 }
 .ui.vertical.menu.navbar{
  margin-top: 0px !important;
 }
}

.ui.vertical.menu{
 margin-top: -15px !important;
 width: 100%;
 display: none;
}

.ui.page.grid{
 padding-left: 2%;
 padding-right: 2%;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/0.13.0/css/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="ui grid">
       <div class="ui blue inverted fixed menu navbar page grid">
            <a href="" class="active item"><i class="home icon"></i></a>
            <a href="" class="item">Calendar</a>
            <a href="" class="item">Leads</a>
            <a href="" class="item">Account Members</a>
            <a href="" class="item">Contacts</a>
            <a href="" class="item">Opportunities</a>
            <a href="" class="item">Quotes</a>
            <a href="" class="item">Documents</a>
            <a href="" class="item">Services</a>
            <div class="right menu">
             <a href="" class="active item"><i class="trash brush icon"></i></a>
             <a href="" class="item"><i class="paint brush icon"></i></a>
             <a href="" class="item"><i class="settings icon"></i></a>
             <a class="ui dropdown item">Owner
              <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
              <div class="menu">
               <div class="item">My Preferences</div>
               <div class="item">Log Out</div>
              </div>
             </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/0.13.0/javascript/semantic.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Fixed navbar works correctly, but I dont know how to add another segment, which is fixed too, below navbar. I use semantic ui as css framework

Answer (score 0):

You can use semantic UI sticky to add a segment to the top of your page. In that segment your can put multiple menu bars, images, nested segments, texts, etc

```
<div class="ui sticky stickyTop">
<div class="ui inverted segment">
    <div class="ui blue inverted menu navbar">
        <a href="" class="active item"><i class="home icon"></i></a>
        <a href="" class="item">Calendar</a>
        <a href="" class="item">Leads</a>
    </div>
    <h3 class="ui header">Stuck Content</h3>
    <p>Add menu bar, images, whatever here!</p>
    <p>You will need to override some semantic UI css, such as margins however. For that, remember to use "<strong>!important"</strong></p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
   //... Your body content
</div>
```

Here's a semi-working code example:
http://jsfiddle.net/sL4fnrz0/3/

I say "**semi-working**" example, since semantic UI sticky only works to a limited extent in code playgrounds...
Try copy the code to a html file instead.